# Setting an environment variable with visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to set an environment variable in Visual Basic 2010 as follows:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Variable", "Value")

 End Sub
End Module
```

But even though the code runs,

When i go to Environment Variables>System Variables
Nothing is there

Can someone please tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the environment variable is only set for the current process (and inherited in any child processes that spawn from it).  You're probably looking for the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) which lets you specify an [EnvironmentVariableTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx) (either Machine or User for your case).

Comment: I did use the EnvironmentVariableTarget option, but still no environment variable added

Comment: Ok i got it to work with EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To set the environment variable for the the current process:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String EnvironmentVariableName, String EnvironmentVariableValue, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

To set the environment variable for the the current user:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String EnvironmentVariableName, String EnvironmentVariableValue, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)
```

To set the environment variable for the the local machine:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String EnvironmentVariableName, String EnvironmentVariableValue, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following steps worked (Excel 2019)

To create/set an environment variable:

```
Dim objUserEnvVars As Object
Set objUserEnvVars = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("User")
objUserEnvVars.item("Test") = "Blah"
```

To read the environment variable:

```
Dim objUserEnvVars As Object
Dim strVar As String
Set objUserEnvVars = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("User")
strVar = objUserEnvVars.item("Test")
MsgBox strVar
```

My reference is: https://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4857

You can use on `.Environment()` to save your variable:

- `"System"`: Returns the system environment variables.
- `"User"`: Returns the current user's environment variables.
- `"Process"`: Returns the environment variables of the current process.
- `"Volatile"`: Returns the current user's volatile environment variables.