# VB Code Equivalent of Batch Code "SET"?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I am making a program that launches an external application, while setting the normally-set Roaming to one of my own folders.
Here is the code in BAT:

set APPDATA=data

To which 'data' is the name of the folder.
However, is there an equivalent of the 'set' code for VB?
Thanks in advance!
Ps. I am new to stackoverflow, so I apologize if I did anything wrong with my questions.

Comment: Why do you need `SET`? What are you trying to do in VB.Net where you need an environmental variable set or changed? `SET` makes a temporary (transient) assignment to an environment variable, which is typically used later in the code. There's no need to resort to that in a VB.Net app; you have any and all of the variables you need available without resorting to the environment.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624213/setting-an-environment-variable-with-visual-basic-2010

Comment: I was actually making a Minecraft launcher, but I had been trying to set the data of the program's app to my own folders, but it kept going to the Roaming folder. So I was trying to use the batch file to do the work. It did, but I kept on thinking if I can find the equivalent of SET.

Comment: Post your code so we can understand how you are trying to do this. Check out the ChDir() support left over from VB6 - might work. You could build the .BAT file dynamically with the SET statement and run that.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I am quite new to the forum. Here is the code, though: